# How to publish a wpf application from Visual Studio so that other people I share my app to can download it

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I have built a windows app in Visual studios, but I am having a hard time publishing it. I want to be able to publish my app somewhere where the people who I share my app with can download and then automatically receive updates. I have tried squirrel, Clickonce, and MSIX installers but none of them work the way I want them to. Is there another option? Also any ideas where I could publish the updates to? I am looking for something cheap (or even better free). Thanks!